# How to highlight my citations in org mode export to latex

Tags: org-mode, terminal-emacs

I am working in a `latex` document using `terminal emacs 26.3` and `org-mode` (`emacs-nox`). But i am facing a tiny problem. Look when i press `C-c C-x [` the mini-buffer prompts `1/1 Regex {&& Regex...}: [someFooWord]:` then i type the name of the author and another buffer shows the possible matches with the citations, then i pressed enter and my citation appears like this `\cite{Oliveira2017}`, this is the same way as in `latex` and the color is the same as the text in `org` (my pdf file is fine), but in `org-mode` my citations gets kind of lost along with the text because of the color. i was wondering if there is a way to change the color or highlight the citations?, to differentiate the my citations and the text. i thought that doing similar to equations or figures (`[[eq:fooEquation]]`) applies to citations but i am wrong, in equations or figures even the color changes to some cyan and they have an underline.
This is my org file.

```
#+latex_class: article                                                              
#+latex_class_options: [a4paper, 11pt]                                                                                                                                                                            
#+latex_header: \usepackage{bookmark}                                               
#+latex_header: \usepackage{amsthm}                                                 
#+latex_header: \hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=bblue}             
#+latex_header: \usepackage{parskip}                                                
#+latex_header: \setlength{\parindent}{15pt}                                                                                                      
#+bibliography: ./refs
#+title: Some title                            
#+author: SomeAuthor                                                      
#+email: SomeMail@gmail.com

* First chapter
#+name: eq:fooEquation                                                                    
\begin{equation}                                                                    
x=\sqrt{b}                                                                          
\end{equation}

This is an equation number [[eq:trial]].

This is a citation \cite{Oliveira2017}.

\bibliography{refs.bib}                                                             
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

my refs.bib file is the next one.

```
@article{Oliveira2017,
    abstract = {This an abstract                                             
    annote = {DONE.},
    author = {Oliveira},
    doi = {10.1016/J.TWS.2017.08.013},
    file = {:home/User/Downloads/a99339b8852ec079008ff92abd755a9f.pdf:pdf},
    issn = {0263-8231},
    journal = {Thin-Walled Structures},
    keywords = {Analysis of variance,Bottle caps waste,Sandwich composites,Tubular \
    honeycomb},
    month = {nov},
    pages = {38--45},
    publisher = {Elsevier},
    title = {{Sustainable sandwich composite structures made from aluminium sheets \
    and disposed bottle caps}},
    volume = {120},
    year = {2017}
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to highlight the word `\cite{Oliveira2017}` with certain color within `org-mode` or even change it to a format similar to one used in equations or figures?

My `myInit.org` for the latex part looks like this

```
◉ Latex                                                                             
    #+begin_src emacs-lisp                                                          
      (require 'ox-latex)                                                           
      (unless (boundp 'org-latex-classes)                                           
        (setq org-latex-classes nil))                                               
      (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes                                               
                 '("article"                                                        
                   "\\documentclass{article}"                                       
                   ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")                             
                   ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")                       
                   ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")                 
                   ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")                         
                   ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))                 
    #+end_src                                                                       
◉ Latex-referencesee                                                                
  #+begin_src emacs-lisp                                                            
  (setq org-latex-pdf-process                                                       
             '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory   
             %o %f"                                                                 
               "bibtex %b"                                                          
               "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory   
               %o %f"                                                               
               "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory   
               %o %f"))                                                             
                                                                                    
  (setq org-latex-logfiles-extensions (quote ("lof" "lot" "tex" "aux" "idx" "log"   
  "out" "toc" "nav" "snm" "vrb" "dvi" "fdb_latexmk" "blg" "brf" "fls" "entoc" "ps"  
  "spl" "bbl" "pygtex" "pygstyle")))                                                
  #+end_src
```

Comment: I'm sure you could change the Org fontification rules to fontify LaTeX citations the way you want, but are you aware that, starting from version 9.5, Org comes with its own citation syntax and citation export processors including BibTeX and biblatex ones? (See the manual: https://orgmode.org/manual/Citation-handling.html and this blogpost: https://blog.tecosaur.com/tmio/2021-07-31-citations.html for more information.) One advantage of using Org's native citations is that they are nicely fontified by default, and it's easy to customize the used faces.

Comment: @Simka Thank you very much for your answer, i was not aware of that, i
check the websites, and i am sure that's what i am looking for. However, i
can not find `org-cite-insert` when i press `M-x` and look for
`org-cite-insert` there is not option available, therefore i was wondering
how to enable that package? or how to make it work?

Comment: It is available in Org mode 9.5 and later, so if you are running an earlier version, you will not have it.